# react native : How to put a label next to the checkbox that also marks the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

How to put a label next to the checkbox that also marks the checkbox?

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
            <CheckBox
              value={Selected}
              onValueChange={() => checkAll()}
              tintColors={{ true: Colors.background_color, false: 'black' }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them both in a TouchableOpacity and set the flexDirection to row like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:'row'}} onPress={checkTheBox}>
            <CheckBox
              value={Selected}
              onValueChange={() => checkAll()}
              tintColors={{ true: Colors.background_color, false: 'black' }}
            />
<Text>Lable</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Example on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/esQad2o4z)

Comment: now works like what is the result ? i added a working example as update for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom checkBox. Hopefully, this will help you alot

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleCheckbox(myItem, item)} style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "center", marginBottom: myItem.index < item.item.answers.length-1 ? 10 : 0}}>
            <Icon name={(item.index == 0 && checkboxArray && checkboxArray[myItem.index] )? "checkbox-outline" : (item.index == 8 && checkboxQ8Array && checkboxQ8Array[myItem.index] ) ? "checkbox-outline" : 'square-outline'} size={25} color={colors.THEME} />
            <Text style={{width: '90%',  marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 14,  color: 'black', fontWeight: '400'}}>{myItem.item.answer}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>`
```